# I have trouble uploading a 2gb folder to github?

Tags: github, git-push, large-files

So this is my first big project. To keep it short it's a website for a studio that has a lot of images and the file size when uploading to Github is around 2.16gb. I'm uploading it to Github, because I'm going to host it using Digitalocean. Of course there are other options on Digitalocean, but if there is any change I could push the folder to Github, without needing to use a CDN. It would be great. Thank you in advance to anyone who helps.

Comment: GitHub isn't designed for this kind of thing. Especially (at least what this sounds like) because you're working on something closed-source

Comment: So how should i host this next app then?

Comment: Renting webspace really isn't that expensive. Even renting a VPS is only a few Euros/Dollars/Pounds per month and you have all the flexibility you need.